# Debug which path way a Subscriber went down in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Subscriber that should have reached a certain data activity (Update Contact) within my Journey Builder, however this hasn't been met. Reviewing the source Data Extension I can see all the data attributes would lead to my particular pathway.

To TEST the Journey I have duplicated it (the original uses Salesforce Data entry), and reused the same Data Extension to see the which path a particular subscriber goes. When running the test it indicates that the user does reach my Update Contact activity.

Using the Journey History is useless as it only shows which users reached the journey, not what their activities are weirdly.

Answer (score 0):

This undocumented REST API endpoint returns Journey Builder activity by contactKey:

```
POST /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search?$pageSize=500&$page=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: YOURTENANTHERE.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
{
     "start": "2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z"
    ,"end": null
}
```

I haven't found a way to filter it for a single contactKey, but I think it's the info you're looking for.